# How to know if the navigation drawer is open in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `NavigationDrawer` on my Main and when I press the Back button (with the `NavigationDrawer` open) the application quits, I want it to just close the `NavigationDrawer`. In Java, Android has this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  if (DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START))
    DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
  else
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

How to make this in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    //if (drawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(YourNavigationView))
    if (drawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start))
    {
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        // or
        //drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
        //drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(navigationView);
    }
    else
        base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. But I don't get why need the `GravityCompat.Start`, if you know and can explain it to me, will be of great help, anyway you have helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

just delegate the method like this:

```
drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayoutID);
drawerLayout.DrawerOpened += delegate
{
   //code when drawer is opened!
};
```